# SQL Server error :only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @mode int

select 
    @mode = (select top 1 order_dow, count(*) 
             from orders_denorm 
             group by order_dow 
             order by 2 desc)
```

I am trying to find the mode of the `order_dow` column using SQL Server. I get the following error message:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

However, only the query without using the `select @mode` works perfectly fine.

Comment: You seem to have missed the *in the select list* part of the message. How do you assign both `order_dow` and `count(*)` to `@mode` at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the *mode* so you only want one column:

```
select @mode = (select top 1 order_dow from orders_denorm group by order_dow order by count(*) desc);
```

Perhaps you want both:

```
select @mode = order_dow, @mode_cnt = cnt
from (select top 1 order_dow, count(*) as cnt
      from orders_denorm
      group by order_dow
      order by count(*) desc
     );
```